# Как добавить несколько тегов из Select'a на form_for в Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
# app/models/post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, throught: taggings

  def all_tags
    self.tags.map(&:id).join(', ')
  end

  def all_tags=(ids)
    ids.shift
    self.tags = ids.map do |id|
      Tag.where(id: id.strip).first
    end
  end
end

# app/models/tag.rb
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tagging
  has_many :posts
end

# app/models/tagging.rb
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belong_to :tag
  belong_to :post
end

# app/views/posts/new.html.slim
= form_for @post, url: posts_path do |form|
  = form.label :title
  = form.text_field :title

  = form.label :body
  = form.text_area :body

  = form.label :all_tags
  = form.select(:all_tags, Tag.all.collect{ |t| [t.name, t.id] }, { prompt: 'Select' }, { multiple: true } )

  = form.button :submit

# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
...
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :all_tags)
end
```

Подскажите(киньте ссылок) как реализовать добавление тегов как на скрине ниже, для Rails 5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за ответ! Это очень помогло мне, но реализовал multiple select с помощью semantic-ui

*`Gemfile`*

```
gem 'semantic-ui-sass'
```

*`app/assets/javascript/application.js`*

```
//= require semantic-ui
```

*`app/assets/javascript/dropwown.js`*

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.dropdown').dropdown();
});
```

*`app/assets/stylesheets/application.js`*

```
@import 'semantic-ui'
```

*`app/views/layouts/application.html.slim`*

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': true
```

*`app/views/posts/new.html.slim`*

```
= javascript_include_tag 'dropdown.js'
= form.select(:all_tags, Tag.all.collect{ |t| [t.name, t.id] }, {}, { multiple: true, class: 'ui fluid selection dropdown' } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно поняла, что вы хотите получить, то вам нужен jQuery плагин [select2](https://select2.org/) Для рельсов есть готовая [интеграция](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails) в assets pipeline